# Why doesn't this provide multiple definition error?

Tags: c++, destructor

I used to write definitions of my virtual destructors inline for ease, even though it didn't fell right. Today I decided to do a little test to understand what happens.

dummy.h

```
#ifndef DUMMY_HEADER
#define DUMMY_HEADER

#include <iostream>

class Dummy
{
public:
        virtual ~Dummy() {std::cout << "dummy destroyed" << std::endl;}
};

class DummyEx : public Dummy
{
public:
        virtual ~DummyEx() {std::cout << "DummyEx destroyed" << std::endl;}
};

#endif
```

deleter.cpp

```
#include "dummy.h"

void deleteDummy(Dummy* dummy)
{
        delete dummy;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "dummy.h"

void deleteDummy(Dummy* dummy);

int main()
{
        Dummy* dummy = new DummyEx();
        delete dummy;
        dummy = new DummyEx();
        deleteDummy(dummy);
        return 0;
}
```

I compiled `deleter.cpp` with `g++ -c deleter.cpp` and I got `deleter.o`

I compiled `main.cpp` with `g++ -c main.cpp` and I got `main.o`

I linked object files with `g++ deleter.o main.o` and I got `a.out`

When I execute `a.out`, output was as expected, both couts from `Dummy` and `DummyEx` destructors were there.

But, to which object file does the compiled definition of destructors go? They cannot have gone to both object files since I didn't get a multiple definition error when linking. Also, compiler has not inlined destructors too because virtual functions were correctly called.

Comment: The one-definition rule does not apply to inline functions. Your destructors are implicitly inline. The language spec just says this has to work. Are you asking how the compiler/linker make this work?

Comment: The ODR does apply to inline functions, but it specifies that they have to have exactly the same definition if there are multiple definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions are implicitly `inline`, which allows multiple definitions to exist as long as they are lexically identical.

Comment: So any inline function can have definitions in more than one object file as long as they are identical? If so, it explains this.

Answer (score 0):

[Functions declared in the body of a class are implicitly declared with `inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17141827), so you won't run into the "multiple definitions" error when linking.